# Was the Ark of the Covenant ever cleaned

Tags: yom-kippur, cleaning, ark-aron-kodesh, blood

Was the blood that was sprinkled on the Ark on Yom Kippur allowed to dry and accumulate through the centuries, or was there a provision for cleaning the Holy of Holies and the Ark in particular?

Comment: Ken, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing this interesting question here! As @sabbahillel pointed out, pretty much the same question was recently asked and answered here, so this question will likely be designated a duplicate of that one. This is great, since people who search Google using terminology similar to yours will now be more likely to find the material. I hope you'll look around at some of our other [tag:beis-hamikdash] Q&As and keep posting.